# jar -tf printing classes inside jar file

Tags: java, jar

I am trying print classes in jar file with

`jar -tf catalina-balancer.jar | grep "class$"`

it returns
`java.io.FileNotFoundException: catalina-balancer.jar (Access is denied)`

I have `-rwx------+ 1 rony rony 16283 mar 21  2013 catalina-balancer.jar`

Comment: Is your username "rony" on that box?

Comment: `+` after the permission bits indicates that **ACL or other 'alternate' access control** applies to this file. Try `ls -Z` (or `--context`) and `getfacl` on the file, and if those don't help, identify the OS (or distro) you are running on.